# Camel Apns component readtimeout and connectiontimeout have no access to set

Tags: apache-camel, apple-push-notifications

I am using camel apns component in order to push send notifications but I did not find any timeout setter for both reading and connection.

As I have seen:

There is this class , **ApnsConnection**, and it includes that parameters. But **ApnsServiceFactory** uses **ApnsBuilder** class as default. In its **getService()** method, setting of these two timeouts is not implemented.

So the question is, am I missing something or are the timeout settings really missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout settings are missing but that doesn't mean you can't do this, looking in the [source code for ApnsServiceFactory](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-apns/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/apns/factory/ApnsServiceFactory.java) you can see a protected method called configureServiceBuilder(ApnsServiceBuilder serviceBuilder) which is used in the testing of the class (which gives a good example usage) and means you can add extra configuration to the builder.

Subclass the ApnsServiceFactory and override configureServiceBuilder. In the body of that override add your `withConnectionTimeout()` and `withReadTimeout()` to the passed in serviceBuilder and return it.

Comment: I totally missed that part of it. you are right. But this definitely is a bug in my opinion, needs to be fixed. THX